# Copy text event from Android share sheet

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharesheet

We wanted to detect if user clicked on copy option available on android share sheet. Is it possible? We want to do it for tracking purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to directly detect if a user clicked on the "copy" option on the Android share sheet. The Android operating system does not provide an API or event specifically for tracking when a user selects the "copy" option from the share sheet.

However, you can implement a workaround by leveraging the Android ClipboardManager. You can monitor changes to the clipboard and infer that the user might have copied something if the clipboard content changes shortly after the share sheet is dismissed. Keep in mind that this approach won't provide direct information about which option the user selected, but it can give you an indication that copying may have occurred.

Here's a basic example of how you can listen for clipboard changes in Android:

1. Implement a `ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener`:

```java
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
        // Clipboard content has changed, handle it here
        // This could indicate that the user copied something from the share sheet
    }
});
```

2. Register the listener in your activity or service where you want to track clipboard changes.
3. When the user interacts with the share sheet and dismisses it, monitor the clipboard for changes within a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh for work around solution.